# bitmapFactoryOptions.outWidth and Height are returning -1

Tags: android, image, resampling

I have a picture file captured by the camera.

The path is

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyyyy/files/Pictures/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_overviewPicture_17417005982933606358.jpg
```

With File file = new File(pathName) I get a valid file and a size about 25 MB :-)

**Code**

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName,bmOptions);
int inSampleSize = Math.min(bmOptions.outWidth/App.PICTURE_WIDTH_MAX,bmOptions.outHeight/App.PICTURE_HEIGHT_MAX);
```

I try to get the x and y values to scale it down.
But only -1 for both values is returned. Any ideas?

App-Level is `23-28` with destination `28.`

Comment: There's a decoding error: `outHeight will be set to -1 if there is an error trying to decode.` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options

Comment: Thanks, that's right. The above mentioned file-size was a misunderstanding. I used File.getTotalSpace() and this a static method of the class and has nothing to do with the file. With file.length() I get 0. With File[] files.. I get the picture name. Bizarr.

Comment: The size of the picture files were 0, so they could not be encoded. I never expected that. I recommendif(new File(pathName).length==0) return false or similar. Thanx for reading / comment!

Answer (score 0):

The size of the picture files were 0, so they could not be encoded. I never expected that. I recommend to check with

```
    if(new File(pathName).length() == 0) return false
```

or similar before trying to decode. Thanx for reading / comment!